# sql - get parentID with or without child in self refrenced table

Tags: mysql, sql, self-referencing-table

Here is my table's (events) content. eventID is "primary key" and parentID is "foreign key" with references to events(eventsID)

self referenced table :

```
    eventID eventName parentID appFK
    1       evt1      null     2
    2       evt2      1        1
    3       evt3      1        1
    4       evt4      null     3
    5       evt5      8        3
    6       evt6      null     4
    7       evt7      null     1
    8       evt8      null     1
```

and another table content (applications) like this :

```
    
    appID appName 
    1     app1      
    2     app2      
    3     app3      
    4     app4
```

I'd like to fetch all eventIDs which are parents or not with a given appID. If a child has the given appID, i'd like to get his parentID and not himself. So the result is going to be like this with appID = 1 :

```
    eventID eventName ParentID appFK
    1       evt1      null     2     // parent event who has children with appID = 1
    7       evt7      null     1     // event with no child and appID = 1
    8       evt8      null     1     // parent event with appID = 1 and has a child
```

I tried lot of examples and read a lot of solutions here but i didn't find a problem like this. Can you help me to write the right SQL ?

thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(e2.eventID, e1.eventID), 
       COALESCE(e2.eventName, e1.eventName),
       COALESCE(e2.appFK, e1.appFK)
FROM events AS  e1
LEFT JOIN events AS e2 ON e1.parentID = e2.eventID AND e1.appFK = 1
WHERE (e1.appFK = 1 AND e1.parentID IS NULL) OR (e2.eventID IS NOT NULL)
```

The `LEFT JOIN` fetches *parent* records (`e1.parentID = e2.eventID`) of a child having appID = 1 (`e1.appFK = 1`).

The `WHERE` clause selects root records having `appID = 1` *and* root records that are related to a child having `appID = 1` (`e2.eventID IS NOT NULL`).

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/926c6/2)

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, it works very fine. but my problem is more complicated then my example here. i can't do `LEFT JOIN events AS e2 ON e1.parentID = e2.eventID AND e1.appFK = 1` because the condition appID is a variable, there will be other conditions like environementID = 25 or responsableID = 45 which are the filter values selected dynamically by the user. So i have to add all these conditions dynamically after LEFT JOIN, and it's going to be complicated like this way.

Comment: i deleted the condition `1.appFK = 1` in `LEFT JOIN` and modified the where clause like this 
`WHERE e1.appFK = 1 AND (e1.parentID IS NULL OR e2.eventID IS NOT NULL)` it works too. Thanks again.